# Removing background color in the form in IE

Tags: css

Am not able to remove the background color in an IFrame so please help me.Am running out of my precious time :-(

Comment: Please elaborate. This does not seem PHP related (more HTML and/or CSS). Could you post an example of code or something? Also, do you have capabilities of editing the content within the iFrame? If so, this can be (if I understand the problem correctly) fixed with CSS.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience i will post the URL in which  form appears to be with white background even though i have given in Css background as none.

Comment: Here is the URL please check in IE http://www.orangerich.net.in/trialad.php

Answer (score 3):

Though this is not PHP related, I think you are seeking for an answer as follows. If you have access to editing the content of the page that is being directed to with the iFrame, then you can use a simple CSS property to remove the background. Try adding this to the head of the document:

```
<style type="text/css">
     body {
         background-color:transparent;
     }
</style>
```

If this page will be accessed at anytime outside of the iFrame, simply set a PHP (if-statement should work if you set a certain variable) to enable/disable this bit of code if it's being accessed by the iFrame page.

In your iframe add this parameter

```
allowtransparency="true"
```

So your iframe should look something like this (copied from your page)

```
<iframe src="http://www.orangerich.info/crm/freetrialform/form.php" height="360" width="320" frameborder="0" scrolling="No" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Good luck!
Dennis M.

Comment: Thank you dennis but still i face the same problem

Comment: Ah, sorry this is IE. I apologize for missing that. CSS in iframes is not supported in IE (even latest), so I will try to find an alternative here in the next few minutes (most likely PHP or javascript).

Comment: @Waseem: I believe I have found the solution you are looking for. I updated my answer. Good luck!

Comment: @Waseem: I have updated my answer. It is the "allowtransparency" parameter. I dug this up after a bit of research.

Comment: But no that is also not working out i have tried using that yesterday

Comment: @Waseem: You have used this along with the transparency CSS code? I have used these two in combination and works properly for me (observe http://raged.microsonic.org/test). The iframe directs to http://raged.microsonic.org/test/content.php which, as you can see, is not red like it is found in the iframe.

Comment: K Mr.Ridge thanks for the post its working fine now..... Actually was doing a minor mistake ... So now its 5ne

Comment: @Waseem: Great, hope all is well! Good luck with future projects!

Comment: Yes it is sucessfull when people like u support us Thank you again wish you the same..Good Luck